# PostgreSQL serial conflict after restore

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I need to export my database, which has the form of:

```
users(
id serial primary key,
name text,
surname text
)

object(
objectID integer primary key,
....
)


edits(
userID integer references (user.id),
objectID integer references (object.objectID),
...
)
```

However when i export my db with pg_dump it looks like this:

```
insert into users(1,'Paul','Swanson');
insert into users(4,'Bob','Vincent');
```

PostgresSQL is not using the sequence behind the serial column nor it updates the sequence after each insert.

So the question is... is it possible that fixing the column of a serial datatype (actually an integer data type) will cause problems later on?
I mean if I do:

```
insert into users('Mindy', 'Blue');
```

Is it possibile that postgresSQL will propose and ID which is already used? Maybe it will propose the first ID 1. I suspect that it should be possible because in the back-up of the database the user ID is fixed and so i suspect that the sequence behind the serial column ID is not updated.

Comment: The script generated by `pg_dump` should contain a `setval()` call for the involved sequences to sync the sequence with the manual supplied values

Comment: Yes that can cause an issue later on. Since as you said the sequence will not be updated this way, and whenever postgres hits an existing sequence, the transaction will fail. This results in inconsistent behaviour. So either you have to use setval and have to mess with the dump itself (which can be really annoying if you have a lot of contraints) or you can update the sequence to the current max value. This is not a clean solution and means your sequence might miss ranges.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes you right, at the end of the file there are the setval(...) with the last ID used. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

As @a_horse_with_no_name says there is the setval(...) at the end of the file wich updates the sequence with max ID inserted in the table.